# Magento Multivendor seller admin panel not working in the magento 2.3.3

Tags: admin

I have installed the  Marketplace Multi Vendor extension.Both  production and staging installed but staging is working  fine.but the production has  some error shown.The issue is creating the  one seller in front end is created , but the back end notification only show no back end admin panel visible  on the particular seller  and not approve the option.kindly give me any solution for all.

Answer (score 0):

You have to approve that seller (which was created from the frontend) from the admin backend panel.

Admin -> Marketplace Management -> Manage Seller -> Select that seller and approve from the action dropdown.

Make sure in the Configuration setting, "Allow seller separate dashboard" = Yes